# Slightly off topic questions from Web Search User

Tags: discussion

From my understanding the [Web Search User](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/454) is used to get questions that were searched for from basicallymoney.com via Google.  It appears though as some of them get added they are slightly off topic.

Examples:

- [Why do consultants or contractors make more money than employees?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2164)
- [What questions to ask a prospective employer when receiving a job offer?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/2211) - This question is already getting answers that are tailored to personal finance.
- [Can I ask my employer if I can work as a contractor instead of an employee?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1680)

As suggested [here](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9/do-technical-questions-about-tools-belong/14#14) should we just go ahead and modify these questions to more align with the intent of the site?

Comment: That guy was a bum anyways, he never accepted an answer!!

Answer (score 4):

I say feel free to modify them if you think you can make them better questions.

BTW, they were added by a human being – **me** – based on questions I saw in Google search analytics.  There's no automated process to pull the questions ... it was just something I was doing to add some questions to the site when things were slow.  Stack Exchange 1.0 did not have a large group of committed beta users standing by to post interesting questions ;-)

Anyway, in some cases the "Web Search User" questions were word-for-word from the search analytics (with spelling or capitalization corrections only), and in others I expanded very slightly, but without trying to guess too much what the question was really trying to get at, or otherwise editorialize.  But maybe some community insight could make them better questions.  I see no reason why we shouldn't edit them.

Though: why do you think they're off-topic?  Contractor vs. employee: I think those are on-topic because understanding how individuals choose or arrange to earn income should be included in "personal finance and money" (Within reason: should keep *"Make $$$$ at home in your spare time!"* scams away...?)

Comment: I assumed it was you and wasn't trying to criticize; I'm all for it. My concern is questions that don't directly address the personal finance reason for asking. In contractor v employee there are other non finance related things that may get answered (working conditions, hours, promotions, job assignments) hence leading the question away from the personal finance aspect. This in turn would lead to more questions like this (general in nature) being asked and the strong personal finance goal of the site being slightly eroded. I like questions to be explicit in relation to the topic.